# Writing a well rounded lyrics with incredible musicality and incredible poetry

Tags: poetry, lyrics

Most songs use very simple language that resonate within their readers. They use short sentences that are simple and have a strong emotional impact, because they are short and thus lyrical (easy to sing it).

> I learned the hard way
>
> You broke my heart
>
> Left it in pieces
>
> In the shack of our past
>
> Feel and hear the voice
>
> Of my heart
>
> The lingering hope
>
> Still beats deep within me

Just wrote this in a rush without much thinking.

Great poems, not all of them, have longer verses, and very poor "lyricality". They are hard to sing, they are meant to be read. However, they seem to be, in some aspects, much deeper and more meaningful.

> March! The mud is cakin' good about our trousies.
>
> Front! -- eyes front, an' watch the Colour-casin's drip.
>
> Front! The faces of the women in the 'ouses
>
> Ain't the kind o' things to take aboard the ship.

The above comes from "Birds Of Prey March"" by Rudyard Kipling:

So how would you go about writing a lyric for a song that share the same the strengths of both, but none of their weaknesses?

Comment: I am not sure, but it is possible that Edgar Allan Poe has written an essay on his approach to writing poems.

Comment: Which do you want to write - lyrics or poetry?

Comment: @NofP see EAP's [The Philosophy of Composition](https://www.eapoe.org/works/essays/philcomp.htm) for the essay itself, and the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Philosophy_of_Composition) for a good summary of the main points. And of course there's his marvellous satire [How to Write a Blackwood Article](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/How_to_Write_a_Blackwood_Article) ("article" here meaning *short story* - see the summary on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Predicament#How_to_Write_a_Blackwood_Article)).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Poetry used to have the noble purpose of holding the knowledge and history of a people. They were relatively easy to memorize and could be sung or spoken.

Blake said he never wrote poetry, he took divine dictation.

Poetry often uses shifts of emphasis and changes of rhythm - such would be difficult to sing. That is not a problem as there are two very different art forms that you seem to be confusing or wishing to merge.

Lyrics require music to be complete, and are written to be sung - often with a melody that has already been written.

Poetry is complete unto itself. Kublia Khan does not require a pianist to be gorgeous - the music is in the carefully crafted genius of the piece itself.

Poetry seeks to move the reader and is often savoured slowly. Song lyrics move at the pace of the music they are sung to and are trapped in that. There is no time to appreciate a well turned phrase or brilliant image - it is gone and the next has replaced it.

> Our sincerest laughter
>
> With some pain is fraught;
>
> Our sweetest songs are those that tell of saddest thought - PBS

This has power, grace, beauty and internal music - needing nothing external to render it beautiful. It is also true - as good poetry often is. Of course, Shelley is more than good.

Reducing poetry to mere song lyrics would be unfortunate. Some verse can be sung - I love Schiller’s powerful words combining flawlessly with Beethoven’s powerful strains, but it was Beethoven who adapted to the poem, creating his unforgettable piece.

Comment: Interesting that you mention Schiller. I was just thinking how a lot of Pushkin's poetry is sung, including his novel in verse *Yevgeni Onegin*, adapted into an opera by Tchaikovsky. Could be it's some weird aspect of the English language that doesn't render itself well to something?

Comment: English is an odd language with influences from many others and so many adopted words, but I think it has more to do with intent. Songwriters intend to write a song, poets to essentially compose a poem. The best poem I have ever written came to me while I was cleaning the barn - a pristine couplet that flowed into the next. By the time I had finished cleaning the barn, I had a ballad that I kept chanting so I would not lose it and could commit it to paper. When writing a poem, I never wonder if it might be sung. I only tried writing a few songs - the constraints were different.